# Loading libraries in Dr Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

I am working through SICP using Dr Scheme.

How do I load external libraries in Dr Scheme? Say I want to use Math library then how do I ask Dr Scheme to load the particular library?

I tried with the following:
**(require (lib "math.ss"))**

Got the following error:
**reference to undefined identifier: require**

I have chosen R5RS as the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the language to Pretty Big. 'require' is not an [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) feature.

Answer (score 3):

Use this for r5rs:

```
(#%require (lib "math.ss"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in R5RS, but it works under the Pretty Big language. Will that be good enough for your assignments?